# HP ENVY 14 SPECTRE Notebook memory upgrade

Tags: windows, memory

I'm planning to upgrade my memory and found Mac Memory 8GB 1600MHz DDR3 SODIMM RAM For Apple iMac MacBook Mac Pro

is it compatible for

HP ENVY 14 SPECTRE Notebook PC 
Serial Number: 5CD2165QTR

According to this site I can use 
[www.crucial.com/usa/en/envy-14-3100eg-spectre/CT4005352](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/envy-14-3100eg-spectre/CT4005352)

Crucial 8GB DDR3L-1600 SODIMM CT4005352 | ENVY 14-3100eg SPECTRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is a HP ENVY 14-3015tu SPECTRE supports only DDR3 1333MHz memory.

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/HewlettPackardENVY143015tuSPECTRE.html